# Replace symbols in python script on distribution

Tags: python, distutils

I have a python script that outputs the program name, version number and the author when called with command line arguments like --help or --version. Currently this information is hardcoded in the python script itself. But I use distutils for building/packaging the application so all this information is already present in the setup.py. Is it possible to let distutils write metadata like version and author name/email to the built python script so I only need to maintain this data in the setup.py file? Or is there another standard mechanism to handle stuff like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it the other way around.  Add the version number, the author name and other metadata you need in the script to the script itself.  Then `import` or `execfile()` the script in `setup.py`, and use the metadata defined in the script as arguments to the `setup()` function.

Answer (score 2):

Have a file `__version__.py` in your package's root, create it on build with setup.py and fetch version information from it for --help or --version. That's how [Mercurial](http://selenic.com/hg/file/20a54bdf2328/setup.py#l176) rolls.

Comment: Yes, this is the best way to do it. As a bonus, if your version.py contains only simple assignments like `version='0.1.2'`, then the file can also be parsed by bash, which is helpful for situations where you have to run a shell script that needs to know the package's version number.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use sed. The man page for sed is [Here](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sed).

Do get that for windows (if you're using windows) it is right [Here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm). It usually comes pre-installed on Linux, Unix, and OS X.

Comment: But this has nothing to do with pythons distutils. I don't want to call special commands before doing "./setup.py install".